# Mysql not processing special characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

When inserting the string "Up to HM77 based models − Intel® Core™ i5" mysql is giving error "Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x88\x92 In...' for column 'spec_1'".

I know this has something to do with characters getting copied from MS-Office.

I have got some idea from [this](http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql) but still dont know why it is happening. What is the best way to resolve this?

Edited to add sqlfiddle on request--

You can try the below query in sqlfiddle.com to get the idea of the error

```
CREATE TABLE product_content ( spec_1 varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1752 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; insert into product_content (spec_1) values('Up to HM77 based models − Intel® Core™ i5')
```

Comment: what is the charset of your table/field?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: here you go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce901 .. since its having error its not saving it

Comment: Here is the full query : CREATE TABLE `product_content` (
  `spec_1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1752 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into product_content (spec_1) values('Up to HM77 based models − Intel® Core™ i5')

Comment: Refrain from using Latin1. Choose unicode/UTF8 if you want to be able to store *any* character.

Comment: well I am changing the CHARSET to UTF8. I am getting this error now "Row size too large". I have got some idea from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html. But they say these calculation do not aply to innodb. I am using Innodb then why am I getting this error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the charset to UTF-8 and it resolved the issue.

It was showing row size too large because I was having lot of columns as varchar(1000). I changed those columns to TEXT/BLOB and it resolved the issue.

If you are having this issue then :

1) Change the encoding of the table to UTF-8
2) If while changing the encoding it shows "Row size too large", check if you have lot of varchar columns. 
3) Change those varchar columns to text/blob